# Getting attribute of element matching a certain value in xml and php

Tags: php, xml, api

Hi am trying to access an element that contains an attribute = a certain value. I am using the Expedia API and I can not get it to work. Here is how I am connecting to the xml file:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
$fp = fopen('room.xml','w'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=13&apiKey=4sr8d8bsn75tpcuja6ypx5g3&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/535.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/17.0.963.79+Safari/535.11&customerSessionId=&xml=<HotelInformationRequest><hotelId>".$hid."</hotelId><options>0</options></HotelInformationRequest>");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
$val = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);//Close curl session 
fclose($fp); //Close file overwrite 
$data = simplexml_load_file('room.xml');
```

Then here is an example of the xml response:

```
 <ns2:HotelInformationResponse xmlns:ns2="http://v3.hotel.wsapi.ean.com/" hotelId="121196">
    <customerSessionId>0ABAA871-3187-D691-3682-CC27421918AC</customerSessionId>
    <HotelSummary order="0">...</HotelSummary>
    <HotelDetails>...</HotelDetails>
    <Suppliers size="2">...</Suppliers>
    <RoomTypes size="9">
    <RoomType roomCode="17918" roomTypeId="136767">
    <description>Deluxe Sunset View</description>
    <descriptionLong>
    One king or two double beds. 38.5 meters (414 square feet). Floors 1–9. Complimentary wireless Internet access. CD/DVD player. MP3 docking station. Complimentary newspapers. Minibar. Coffeemaker. Bathroom with shower only. Aveda toiletries. Bathrobes. Bathroom scale. Laptop-compatible safe. Turndown service.
    </descriptionLong>
    </RoomType>
    </RoomTypes>
```

And lastly here is how I am trying to access it:

```
<?php $dataroom = $data->RoomTypes->RoomType['@roomCode="17918"']->description; var_dump($dataroom);  ?>
```

As you can see I am trying to access description where roomCode = 17918. But it will not work!! I have tried using an echo and print and nothing works. The var_dump returns the value of NULL. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I can get any other element I want but not where I need it to match.

Comment: Perhaps you should append `->data` to the end of `description`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out... thank you everyone for your help.. definitely helped me in the right direction! Here is how I resolved it:

```
foreach($data->RoomTypes->RoomType AS $match){
    if($match['roomCode']== "$roomCode"){
      echo $match->descriptionLong;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dataroom = get_object_vars($data->RoomTypes->RoomType); 
if($dataroom['@attributes']['roomCode'] == 17918) echo $dataroom['description'];
```

Of course you will have to add extra loops accordingly, but this should work just fine, I have only tested it with an online code execution tool and seems to work.

The method you are trying is not particularly correct. You are trying to access an object as an array. I am converting the object into an array and then I am accessing it as an array.